# resque , redis and rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi anyone can give me idea what i need to install to setup resque and redis on my rails 2.3.8 application.

I have installed.

```
gem install redis
gem install redis-namespace
gem install resque 
gem install json
```

after that i have tried to run rake task from my application.

```
C:\test>rake redis:install
(in C:/cyncabc)
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'redis:install'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

getting this error.

I have installed gem not plugin.
what's the problem with it ? and what's the solution?

Comment: Have you first try this : "git clone git://github.com/defunkt/resque.git" and "cd resque" before "rake redis:install dtach:install"?

Comment: I am not using git. how is it possible to execute this command?? And i am working on windows so will it work on windows?

Comment: You can download a git program for Windows. It works well.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the dependencies :

```
gem install redis redis-namespace yajl-ruby
```

If you can't install yajl-ruby try with json :

```
gem install redis redis-namespace json
```

Then run this command line :

```
./script/plugin install git://github.com/defunkt/resque
```

Everything is notice in the [doc](http://github.com/defunkt/resque)!

EDIT

To install with gem :

In "config/environnement.rb" write this :

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
    # ...
    config.gem 'redis', :source => 'http://gemcutter.org'
    config.gem 'resque', :source => 'http://gemcutter.org'
    # ...
end
```

Then type the command :

```
rake gems:install
```

If you want to control installed librairies :

```
gem list
```

Answer (score 0):

Anytime I've had to do it, I've managed to do it very well with [this documentation](http://github.com/defunkt/resque)

Comment: i have checked that doc but i am still confused about installation.
can you just list out the things which i need to install to set up.
i am on windows.

Comment: Don't know how to do it on Windows, sorry :(